# Lemma of Characterictic Subgroups

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism, automorphism-group, characteristic-subgroups

Let G is group and K is subgroup of G then

"K is characteristic in G  $\Leftrightarrow $ $\forall k\in K$ and $\forall \phi \in Aut(G)$ , $\phi (k)\in K$.

**Here is my solution:** $\Rightarrow :$ Let K is characteristic in G. Then for all $\phi \in Aut(G)$ we have $\phi (K)=K$ (definition of characteristic subgroup) .

Since $k\in K$ , $\phi (k)\in \phi (K)=K$.

But I could not show the $(\Leftarrow ):$ part.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Since $\phi \in {\rm Aut}(G) \Rightarrow \phi^{-1} \in {\rm Aut}(G)$, we have $\phi(k),\phi^{-1}(k) \in K$, and so $\phi(K) = K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi\in \text{Aut}(G)$.
Since $\phi(k)\in K$ for all $k\in K$, we have $\phi(K)\subseteq K$.

Note that $\phi^{-1}\in \text{Aut}(G)$.
By the assumption, we have $\phi^{-1}(k)\in K$ for all $k\in K$, which implies that $k\in \phi(K)$ for all $k\in K$. Thus we have $K\subseteq \phi(K)$.